# GraphQL fallback query if no results

Tags: graphql

I have the following query:

```
{
     entity(id: "theId") {
         source1: media(source: 1){
             images{
                 src, alt
             }
         }
         source2: media(source: 2){
             images{
                 src, alt
             }
         }
     }
}
```

That give me a result like:

```
{
    "entity": [
      {
        "source1": {
            "images": [{"src": "", "alt": ""}]
        },
        "source2": {
            "images": [{"src": "", "alt": ""}]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to have a single result of `source1` and `source2`, executing `source1` and if it has no result it use `source2` as fallback?

Answer (score 0):

You are querying two fields (source1, source2) so something has to come back for both of them (null being a possible option). If you want to check them in a sequence you should probably break the query in two and run them one at the time from the client.

Could you perhaps change so you only query a single `source` field and have the resolver (on the server) return what makes sense based on what is available, so to speak? Like this:

```
{
     entity(id: "theId") {
         source: media(sourcesList: [1, 2]){
             images{
                 src, alt
             }
         }
     }
}
```

where `sourceList` is the sources to try, in order. So the resolver (server) can then check if source 1 is available and if not return source 2.

You could also add a field to let the client know which source was actually returned from the proposed list (`sourceNumberReturned` below would return `1` if source 1 was returned, otherwise `2`).

```
{
     entity(id: "theId") {
         source: media(sourcesList: [1, 2]){
             images{
                 src, alt
             }
             sourceNumberReturned
         }
     }
}
```